# Error:request for member of non class type

Tags: c++, class, object

I was just trying a simple program that calculates the volume of a cube. I have declared the object in main and when I try accessing the function of the class with user input arguments it shows an error : request for member 'volume cube' in 'vol', which is of non class type 'Vellimi()'. Why does this occur ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vellimi {
private:

double width;
double height;
double length;

public:
Vellimi(double,double,double);
double volume_cube (double width,double height,double length)
{
    return width*height*length;
}

};
  Vellimi::Vellimi(double a,double b,double c){
  width=a;
   height=b;
   length=c;
}
int main()
{
   double x,y,z;

   Vellimi vol();

   cout<<"Input the width : "<<endl;
   cin>>x;
   cout<<"Input the height : "<<endl;
   cin>>y;
   cout<<"Input the length : "<<endl;
   cin>>z;
   cout<<"The volume is "<<vol.volume_cube(x,y,z)<<endl;
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: _`Vellimi vol();`_ Actually declares a function. Just write `Vellimi vol;`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have tried that and it still shows an error

Comment: Sorry, I should have written `Vellimi vol(0.0,0.0,0.0);` since `Vellimi` doesn't have a default constructor. What you have still is a function declaration, hence the confusing error message.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks, fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just became a victim of C++'s [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Change this:

```
Vellimi vol();
```

to

```
Vellimi vol(0, 0, 0); //or
//Vellimi vol; Unfortunately, you have no default constructor
```